# Serial port stops while running code on Ubuntu 12.04 ros hydro and needs a reboot to start again

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, serial-port, ros

We have got a code to send some messages to a motordriver.
We have created a ROS node with a cpp code (below).
The code works, but after a while the serial port is killed.
If we try to restart the node, we can't re-open the serial port.
We tried also to open the port with CuteCom (terminal). But CuteCom can't open the port as well.
We have made the code with different libraries (termios.h and SerialStream.h) but they give the same error.
We've watched the log files from Linux (dmesg). After we ran the node again there will be an error like this: LSR safety check engaged.

We can't find the problem. Hopefully there is someone who can help us.

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include "ros/ros.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace LibSerial;

int main(int argc, char **argv  )
{
    //initialize ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "uart");

    //define a nodehandle and define the rate for the "ros while loop"
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate rate(100);

    ROS_INFO("Ros is initialized");


    //
     // Open the serial port.
    //
     SerialStream serial_port;
     char c;
     ROS_DEBUG("Serial Port will be opened");
     serial_port.Open("/dev/ttyS8") ;
    //check if serial port opens correctly
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not open serial port.");
        return(1);
     }

    ROS_INFO("Serial port is opened");

     //
     // Set the baud rate of the serial port.
     //
     serial_port.SetBaudRate( SerialStreamBuf::BAUD_115200 ) ;
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not set the baud rate.");
        return(1) ;
     }
    ROS_INFO("baud rate is setted");

     //
     // Set the number of data bits.
     //
     serial_port.SetCharSize( SerialStreamBuf::CHAR_SIZE_8 ) ;
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not set the character size.");
        return(1) ;
     }
    ROS_INFO("char size is setted");

     //
     // Disable parity.
     //
     serial_port.SetParity( SerialStreamBuf::PARITY_NONE ) ;
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not disable the parity.");
        return(1) ;
     }

    ROS_INFO("parity is setted");
     //
     // Set the number of stop bits.
     //
     serial_port.SetNumOfStopBits( 2 ) ;
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not set the number of stop bits.");
        return(1) ;
     }
    ROS_INFO("stop bits are setted");

     //
     // Turn off hardware flow control.
     //
     serial_port.SetFlowControl( SerialStreamBuf::FLOW_CONTROL_NONE ) ;
     if ( ! serial_port.good() )
     {
        ROS_ERROR("Error: Could not use hardware flow control.");
        return(1) ;
     } 
    ROS_INFO("Disabled flow control");

     //
     // Do not skip whitespace characters while reading from the
     // serial port.
     //
     // serial_port.unsetf( std::ios_base::skipws ) ;
     //
     // Wait for some data to be available at the serial port.
     //
     //
     // Keep reading data from serial port and print it to the screen.
     //
     // Wait for some data to be available at the serial port.


  //
  //    while( serial_port.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0 )

    while(ros::ok())
     {
        char out_buf[8];

        //Define data
        out_buf[0] = 0x5a;
        out_buf[1] = 0xaa;
        out_buf[2] = 0x03;
        out_buf[3] = 0x20;
        out_buf[4] = 0x00;
        out_buf[5] = 0x00;
        out_buf[6] = 0x00;
        out_buf[7] = 0x00;

        //write data to serial port.
        if(serial_port.IsOpen()){
            ROS_INFO("1");
                serial_port.write(out_buf, 8);
            ROS_INFO("2");
            //serial_port.writechar
        } else{
            ROS_ERROR("Serial port is closed");
        }

        ROS_INFO_ONCE("We doen het");
            rate.sleep();
     }

    serial_port.Close();
    ROS_INFO("serial port is closed");

//     while(1)
//     {
//         char next_byte;
//         serial_port.get(next_byte);  HERE I RECEIVE THE FIRST ANSWER
//         std::cerr << next_byte;
//
//     }

     return EXIT_SUCCESS ;

}
```